# ROR: Select from multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have two tables: interests and Link_ui (this is for recording user and interest)
I want to input the user id and show all interests name that user have.

In Link_ui controller:

```
 def output
    @interests = LinkUi.find_by_sql [ 'SELECT interests.name FROM link_uis, interests
    WHERE link_uis.interest_id = interests.id AND link_uis.user_id=? ', params['user_id'] ]
```

And input page:

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'output', :method => 'post' %>
  enter id.
  <%= text_field_tag ':user_id', '', 'size' => 30 %>
```

It comes out nothing, but I am sure there is matched data in database. And if I don't input parameter just set link_uis.user_id = 1, it comes out:

```
your search are [#<LinkUi >, #<LinkUi >, #<LinkUi >, #<LinkUi >]
```

What's wrong with this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `find_by_sql` on a *LinkUi* model expects you to return columns from the `link_uis` table, whereas you're selecting just `interests.name`. However, you are picking a bit of a fight with ActiveRecord, there. :)

You usually want to avoid `find_by_sql`, and instead let ActiveRecord generate your SQL for you. Probably most important for your example are associations.

The way I see it, you have a bunch of *Users*, and a bunch of *Interests*. Your *LinkUis* tie these two together (a *LinkUi* belongs to a *User* and an *Interest*). Feel free to correct me on this; this is your business logic as I gather from your example.

These classes (whose names I've emphasized) are your models, defined in the `app/models` directory. The assocations (relationships) between them should be defined on those classes.

---

Start of with a simple association in your *User* model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :link_uis
end
```

And in your *Interest* model:

```
class Interest < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :link_uis
end
```

Then the *LinkUi* model that ties it together:

```
class LinkUi < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :interest
end
```

Now, given any *User*, you can get his/her *LinkUis* by simply saying `user.link_uis.all`, and for each *LinkUi*, you can get the *Interest* as `link_ui.interest`. You can tell ActiveRecord to try and fetch these two in one shot as efficiently as possible using `:include`, and get a list of *Interest* names using the standard Ruby `collect` method. It then becomes:

```
user = User.find params['user_id']
link_uis = user.link_uis.all(:include => :interest)
interest_names = link_uis.collect { |link_ui| link_ui.interest.name }
```

---

You can take it one step further; for any *User*, you can directly get his/her *Interests*. Once you've set up the above associations, you can fold two ‘steps’ into one, like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :link_uis
  has_many :interests, :through => :link_uis
end
```

Which could turn the example into this one-liner:

```
interest_names = User.find(params[:user_id]).interests.collect { |i| i.name }
```

Comment: Hi, it comes out "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in Link uisController#output
Couldn't find User without an ID". But if I use "interest_names = User.find(1).interests.collect { |i| i.name }", it works. 
So, did I do something wrong in input? and I am sure the parameter is sent. Thank you.

Comment: The Rails log-file should show you which form parameters the server sees. I just now noticed you call `text_field_tag` with `':user_id'`, but it should be simply `'user_id'` or `:user_id`. (The former is of the Ruby string type, the latter of the Ruby symbol type.)

Comment: Thanks. It works with :user_id . Really thanks for your kindly help.